# Getting dropdown button id from Datatable on every page

Tags: button, datatable, dropdown

I have a datatable with dropdown buttons on every row and every button has unique IDs and also hidden inputs under it. When I click the button, script is called and DB is manipulated.

[Table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMcMX.png)

```
foreach (var item in Model.UvDevice)
{
    i++;
    <tr>
        <td hidden="hidden">@item.Id</td>
        <td>@i</td>
        <td>@item.Name</td>
        <td>
            <div class="btn-group dropdown">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    @item.UnitName
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="z-index:998; overflow: scroll; max-height: 180px; overflow-x: hidden" role="menu">
                    @foreach (var item2 in Model.Units)
                    {
                        <li>
                            <div type="button" style="z-index: 998" class="btn" onclick="changeDeviceUnit(this)" id="@j">
                                @item2.UnitName
                                <input id="deviceId" type="hidden" value="@item.Id" />
                                <input id="deviceUnitId" type="hidden" value="@item2.UnitId" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        j++;
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </td>
```

Here is the JS code.

```
function changeDeviceUnit(button) {
            var arrayPos = button.id;

            var _deviceId = deviceId[arrayPos].value;
            var _deviceUnitId = deviceUnitId[arrayPos].value;

            var data = {
                unitId: _deviceUnitId,
                deviceId: _deviceId                
            };

            $.post("...", data, function (obj) {

            });
        };
```

It is working when table on the first page however when I moved to other pages, IDs are still in the correct order but **deviceID** and **deviceUnitId** arrays are reordering. Therefore, **arrayPos** can't point the correct place.

For example on second page arrayPos continue with 101 but **deviceID** and **deviceUnitId** arrays are starting from [0].

How can I make it working on every page?

Comment: you set the button id as `@j` and then inside the `changeDeviceUnit` you use that value as the index to retrieve the item in `deviceId` array. Is that correct? it's not clear why you don't have the `deviceId` as a map of the `deviceId` itself and if it was the case, such information would be in its child `input`. Anyway you have the id `deviceId` there and it sounds like it would be duplicated

Comment: Yes "@j" is used as index of the array. deviceId is a value from database. I am using this value in controller to manipulate the correct database element. For example, deviceId is same for many buttons because, buttons are pointing the same device. However, every button has unique ID with help of "@j"

Comment: yes but did you see that your button is wrapping a pair of elements having a static id `<input id="deviceId"`  `<input id="deviceUnitId">`  ..those looks like will be duplicated. Instead of using the `j` index to retrieve the device, why don't you use the `deviceId` itself that can be retrieved once you have the button as `button.querySelector('input.deviceid').value` (as long as you add to it the class `deviceid`).

Comment: Anyway I'm trying to say there are some smoking guns in that code that I addressed in my above comments... but to arrange a meaningful solution it should be first clear what those arrays are supposed to be `deviceId` and `deviceUnitId` .. because the key here is how to retrieve to correct item from those array once you know the coordinates given by the clicked button

Comment: Maybe I can't catch your comments because I am not familiar with JS and HTML. How can I get the deviceId and deviceUnitId at the same time when button is pushed. By the way ,I am having 10 buttons on a single page and 10 more at next page... I thought every button should have unique ID. But if there any other way to do that, I will be happy to guided.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with below approach.

```
@foreach (var item2 in Model.Units)
{
    <li>
        <div type="button" style="z-index: 998" class="btn changeUnitButton" id="@item.Id" value="@item2.UnitId">
            @item2.UnitName
        </div>
    </li>
}
```

Tricky part that, you have to call the button function inside table element when you are working with datatables. Because when you filter or change the page of the table, table is redrawn and new buttons are created. Otherwise, the buttons except first page are not working.

JS:

```
    $('.deviceTable').on('click', '.changeUnitButton', function () {
        var _deviceId = $(this).attr('id');
        var _deviceUnitId = $(this).attr('value');

        var data = {
            unitId: _deviceUnitId,
            deviceId: _deviceId
        };

        $.post("", data, function (obj) {

        });

    });
```